# Passing a string from Assembly x64 to c++

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-c++, assembly, x86-64

i have this c++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

extern "C" int GetAsmX64();

extern "C" void PrintInt(int a) {
    cout << "[ASM]: " << a << endl;
}

extern "C" void PrintString(void* str) {
    char* string = (char*)str;
    cout << str << endl;
}

int main() {
    cout << "x64 says: " << GetAsmX64() << endl;
    _getch();   //stop screen from closing
    return 0;
}
```

With this asm file:

```
extrn PrintInt:proc     ;PrintInt func
extrn PrintString:proc  ;PrintString func

.data

string db 'Hallo string from asm here'

.code

_print_int macro value
    sub rsp, 20h        ;reserve shadow space on the stack
    mov ecx, value      ;first and only parameter
    call PrintInt       ;call function
    add rsp, 20h        ;restore stack
endm

GetAsmX64 proc
    _print_int 111

    sub rsp, 20h        ;reserve shadow space on the stack
    mov cl, string      ;first and only parameter
    call PrintString    ;call function
    add rsp, 20h        ;restore stack

    mov eax, 0          ;return 0 to c++
    ret
GetAsmX64 endp
end
```

So main kicks in and calls the asm procedure.
This works fine.
I have a PrintInt function that can be called from asm to print an interger in the console. This also works. I made a macro in the asm file to make it easy to call the function. Now i want to pass a string from asm to a c++ function to print it, like i can print integers.
This causes problems however. First i tried:

```
extern "C" void PrintString(char* str) {
    cout << str << endl;
}
```

but This will trow a massive amount of errors.
Having a void* str does work however:

```
extern "C" void PrintString(void* str) {
    cout << str << endl;
}
```

It will print an adress (of the string?????)
Though casting will trow more errors:

```
extern "C" void PrintString(void* str) {
    char* string = (char*)str;
    cout << str << endl;
}
```

So the question is, how do i pass the string from asm into the c++ method as char* to print it using cout?

Thanks in advance,

Cody

Comment: What errors? Also your string in the asm is missing the zero terminator.

Comment: I'd use `const char *` but I gather problems stem from this `mov cl, string` . That will move a single character from memory address pointed to by `string` and put that in `cl`. To print a string you want the address of `string` in _RCX_ not a character. Lilely your printing routine fails with errors suggesting some kind of invalid memory address etc.

Comment: So I'd change `mov cl, string` to `mov rcx, offset string` and modify your code to use `char *` as a parameter again and **not** `void *`

Comment: One other subtle issue is that the [Microsoft Calling x86-64 convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx) requires that function calls be done from a point where the stack pointer _RSP_ is 16-bytes aligned. When `GetAsmX64 proc` is reached the return addres on the stack misaligns the stack pointer _RSP_ by 8. You can realign it to 16 by pushing a register on the stack and restoring it before `ret`. So First instruction of `GetAsmX64` could be `push rbx` and just before `ret` do a `pop rbx` . The extra 8 bytes pushed on the stack will realign _RSP_ to a 16-byte boundary.

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution : 'mov rcx, offset str'